# Migrating angular project from 10 to 11

Tags: angular

```
node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts
 Property 'authState' of type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to string index type 'Promise<any> & ((...args: unknown[]) => Promise<any>) & ((...args: unknown[]) => any)'.

19     readonly authState: Observable<firebase.User | null>;

error occur after migrate angular project from 10 to 11
 "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5", "firebase": "^7.24.0"
```

how to solve this error

Comment: Looks like you are trying to fill an observable with a Promise. Can you show the code using that authState ?

Comment: You should handle it as it tells it you :D  Check this link to see the breaking change https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/b4c3da8db8d07ad4bbb34d81f835862658cc441c/docs/version-6-upgrade.md